# Different HCl concentrations and iron nails

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry

Hey guys I am at high school and we have a project on designing our own lab.

1. My questions is will different concentrations such as 10%, 20%, 30% and 37% have an affect on the corrosion of an iron nail.
2. And will different concentrations(0%, 20%, 30% and 37%) have a different pH?
3. Is it possible to measure the corrosion on the iron nail for quantitative data and a graph?

We don't have to do the experiment, we just have to design one.

Sorry I am not good at chemistry, hope some one could take time to answer my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must use similar nails for this experiments.

1. Different concentrations will corrode the nails at different rates. The rates won't increase beyond a certain concentration, no matter how much you increase the concentration. This must be a fun experiment to try
2. Depends on the medium you're going to use for diluting
3. Yes! You can calculate the time that each of it take to corrode the iron completely. A stopwatch will help

Comment: hey another question what do you mean by the medium?

Comment: The nature of the solvent that you're going to use in diluting. Well if you're dilute the acid HCL with *relatively* basic Water, the pH of the solution is going to change. The number of pH will increase

Comment: ohh kk thx a lot :)

Comment: By the way, how will I know the iron is corroded completely? Do I determine it with my naked eye? Sorry for the amount of questions :(